# Type for top level parameter that uses substitution

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have a role that is passed to various parts of a cloudformation stack and I want to define it at the top level to minimize repetition. The problem I have is that there is a substitution within the parameter value and I'm not sure what to define the type as. The substitution is necessary as I want to deploy this in multiple accounts.

ie.

```
MyServiceRole:
Type: 
Description: Service Role used in Maintenance Window SSM docs
Default: !Sub "arn:aws:iam::${AWS::AccountId}:role/my-ssm-maintenance-window-role"
```

Any ideas as to what the type should be defined as? Or should I restructure the `Default` value?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear how you could approach the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas as to what the type should be defined as?

You can define your role as a [nested stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html). This will reduce the amount of replication and allow you to **parametrize your role** based on parent stack where the role is used.

Comment: I looked into this but it seemed like a lot of additional overhead for one parameter sorry. I ended up talking with AWS Support and they said that if I pass in the parameter to the SSM Doc task, it needs to be done as JSON